# Redirect to Apple Maps with "Avoid Highways" automatically selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-maps

We have an app that allows users to check-out and ride a certain type of vehicle, and I want to build a button that, when pressed, redirects them to their default navigation app, optionally with a destination pre-selected. Crucially, this vehicle is not allowed on highways, so we do not ever want to direct users to a route with highways in it.

Right now, I am stuck because it looks like I cannot launch Apple Maps with "avoid highways" selected. I am using the URL `"http://maps.apple.com/daddr=0,0&dirflg=h"`, but `&dirflg=h` did not work for me, neither did `&avoid=highways` or `&avoid=h`. Looking at Apple's documentations, it appears that this param just isn't available: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

It looks like for iOS users I would have to redirect them to use Google Maps instead, which I can do according to the Google Maps iOS SDK docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme. Is that true? Is there really no way to open Apple Maps with 'avoid highways' selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep—from that documentation it looks like there’s indeed no flag for that setting in the request URL. You may want to [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) on MapKit for that feature.

Comment: Thanks. This is unfortunate. I submitted a request at bugreport.apple.com.